# Translation of "awkward" (as in "an awkward situation")

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, definiciones

In English, the word "awkward" can be used to describe a situation that is uncomfortable and embarrassing (but neither word seems to fully describe what "awkward" describes). What is the best translation of this concept in Spanish? If a single word doesn't fully capture the English meaning, what phrase would best describe it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Spanish the best translation for awkward is **incómodo**.

e.g.

> ¡Qué incómodo! >.<

Yes, 'incómodo' can just mean uncomfortable, but also it is used as awkward as in *an awkward situation*.

Comment: You can also say embarazosa. La situación era muy incómoda/embarazosa.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I don't think we have such a precise word as 'awkward' (I've missed it).

As per other answer, "**incómodo**" is the most commonly used word. But because "incómodo" means in general "uncomfortable", this sense is often made more explicit:  **"Una situación incómoda", "Un momento incómodo"**, etc.

Other words are "(momento) **embarazoso**"  (more precise, but less colloquial), or "**violento**" (which also is ambiguous).

Comment: How are your two examples made more explicit?  What would less explicity uncomfortable?

Answer (score 5):

The word "Torpe" has all the flavor and meaning as awkward. And it is used in exactly the same way like "El muchacho es muy torpe" (The boy is awkward) or "Esta en una etapa de torpeza" (His in a awkward stage) as for your sentence "Me siento torpe en esta situacion"

Comment: Wouldn't 'torpe' be better translated as uncoordinated or clumsy?

Comment: I think this is a different sense of awkward (a clumsy person as opposed to an awkward situation).

Comment: there is is a difference but "torpe" is as close as you can get unless some one can thik of another word.

Comment: @Fortunato Gracias por tu aportación. He editado las faltas de ortografía en español. Por favor, de ahora en adelante, cuida la ortografía. Gracias.

Comment: @Laura Muchas gracias ... Es my fustrante el tener un buen vocavulario y poder escribir apropiadamente. Soy Dislecsico y no puedo ver las faltas. Yo se que les molesta a la gente la mala ortografia. Si queren dejo de contestar preguntas.

Comment: @Fortunato o simplemente puedes dejar una nota al pie de tu respuesta pidiendo que el primero que lo vea y pueda editar que edite tus falta, o redactarlas primero en un procesador de textos con corrector. No creo que haga falta dejar de participar. :)

Comment: @Fortunato yo estoy dispuesto a ayudarte a corregir todo eso cada vez que lo vea

Comment: @Fortunato - Sugiero que pongas algo en tu perfil, y que incluyas la explicación al pie de tus respuestas.  También hay spell checkers para browsers, y software que lee en voz alta lo que has redactado. 
 Tus aportaciones son interesantes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **incómodo** which has already been suggested, [Linguee.com](http://linguee.com) (which I suggest you take a look at) also suggests

**delicado, extraño, dificil**

when describing a *situation* (as opposed to a person).  Which is what you appear to be asking about.

*You can help us help you by including a sample context.*

Answer (score 0):

Other two possibilities:

**desagradable** (http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/desagradable)

**espinoso** (http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/espinoso)